# Docker container that creates a SSH tunnel on docker-compose up

Tags: docker, ubuntu, ssh, docker-compose, ssh-tunnel

My `docker-compose.yml` file creates a service `api` listening on port `9000` and a remote server `123.1.2.3` needs to access it. An SSH tunnel is required because there is a firewall preventing direct access to the Docker host port 9000.

```
version: "3.9"

services:
  api:
    image: my/api-service:latest
    ports:
    - "9000:9000"
```

I'm currently manually creating this SSH tunnel by running this command on the Docker host

```
ssh -fN -R 9000:127.0.0.1:9000 root@123.1.2.3
```

Is it possible to create another service in this `docker-compose.yml` file to create this SSH tunnel on running `docker-compose up`, using a SSH private key in the same directory as the `docker-compose.yml` file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be possible.  Looking at [a copy of the **ssh**(1) man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/ssh), the `ssh -R` option sets up a port forward from the remote machine back to the local machine

```bash
ssh -R port:host:hostport
```

where `port` on the remote host is forwarded through the ssh tunnel, making outbound connections to `host:hostport` from the local system.

In your case, if the ssh tunnel was launched from a container, you could use normal Docker networking, and connect to `api:9000`, using the standard port number of the container.

The first thing you'll need is an image with the ssh client.  This is easy enough to build from source, so we'll do that

```bash
FROM ubuntu:22.04
RUN apt-get update \
 && DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive \
    apt-get install --no-install-recommends --assume-yes openssh-client
```

**Do not copy the ssh keys into the image.**  Anything that's in an image can be trivially extracted later, and you don't want to compromise your ssh keys this way.

Instead, we'll [bind mount](https://docs.docker.com/storage/bind-mounts/) our ssh keys into the container when it runs.  ssh is extremely particular about the permissions of the ssh keys, so you need to make sure the container runs as the same numeric user ID as on your host system.  Run

```bash
id -u
```

and remember that number (on an Ubuntu system, it might be 1000).

Now, in the Compose file, in addition to the original server, we need to

1. Build the image;
2. Specify the user ID;
3. Inject the ssh keys;
4. Create some concept of a "home directory"; and
5. Specify the actual ssh command to run.

```yaml
version: '3.8'
services:
  api:
    image: my/api-service:latest
    # ports: ['9000:9000']  # optional
  tunnel:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.ssh
    user: 1000
    volumes:
      - /home/yourname/.ssh:/home/.ssh
    environment:
      HOME: /home
    command: ssh -N -R 9000:api:9000 root@123.1.2.3
```

In the last line the first `9000` is the port number on the remote system, and `api:9000` is the container name and standard port number for the target container.  `ports:` would also publish the port on the local system and aren't required (or considered) for connections between containers.  I've omitted the `ssh -f` option so that the ssh tunnel runs as a foreground process, as the only process in its container.

Comment: I think its almost working! On `docker-compose up`, I get the error `services.tunnel.user must be a string`. Tried `user: "1000"` but I get the error `No user exists for uid 1000` on `docker-compose up`. `id -u` on the docker host shows `1000`

Comment: There isn't usually a requirement to create a user in the container's `/etc/passwd` file but the occasional piece of software does care, and it's possible ssh is in this list.  I don't usually recommend creating a user specifically matching the host user in a Dockerfile but that might be the most expedient approach here.

Comment: (The problem is that ssh requires `$HOME/.ssh` to be mode 0700 and owned by the current user.  The bind mount preserves the numeric ownership and permissions, so you need to make sure the container user matches the host user in this particular case.)

Comment: Thank you, added a line to the `Dockerfile` to run `groupadd` and `useradd` using `ARG`s passed in from `docker-compose.yml`.  This got it working!